# Convert huge number of lists to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

User defined function=> my_fun(x): returns a list

XYZ = file with **LOTS** of lines

```
pandas_frame = pd.DataFrame() # Created empty data frame
for index in range(0,len(XYZ)):
    pandas_frame = pandas_frame.append(pd.DataFrame(my_fun(XYZ[i])).transpose(), ignore_index=True)
```

This code is taking very long time to run like in days. How do I speed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need apply for each row funcion to new `list` by list comprehension and then use only once `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [my_fun(i) for i in range(len(XYZ))]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```